# How to close a view when select any table cell of the same view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am creating an application where I need to fill a textfield with state name (like assam, karnataka etc).I created a button near the textfield. When clicking that button, a tableview (which is populated with lots of state) is added as a subview to that view where the textfield is. My problem is I want to close the table view with state names when user select any one of the states. I added the view as subview but not able to close the view when select a state from it.Please help me.Thanx in advance.

Comment: hi  do u want to remove that table view ? is it right?

Comment: This is now question #13, and a lot of people have helped you already, but you still have not accepted a single answer.

Comment: yes.....but after selecting any cell or state name.....

Comment: or as soon as u select a table cell the vew view should be removed...thanks

Comment: Your question isn't clearly written but it seems like you'd be better using a UIPickerView which is designed to dismiss & disappear whena  selection is made.

Comment: Or you could use a separate view controller and push it modally.

Comment: hey what u have written in the table view did select can u post that piece of code....

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    your_viewController *vc=[[your_viewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:vc];
    [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [navController release];
    [vc release];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil]; 
    youroldview *rvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"identifierof_oldview"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:rvc animated:YES];
}
```

It will navigate to that view if it is navigation based application
otherwise you should use

```
[self presentModalViewController:rvc animated:YES];
```